# Laravel Backpack javascript dynamic change of select option

Tags: laravel-backpack

I am running laravel backpack 3.4 and created a custom select2 fieldtype from the standard one, I am now trying to based on an onchange event change the value selected on another select options but no change is happening

This is the field declararion

```
<select onchange="updateunit(this, '{{$field['name']}}' )"  id="{{$field['name']}}_<% $index %>"  data-index="<% $index %>"
        ng-model="item.{{ $field['name'] }}"
        [ngValue]="value"
        @include('crud::inc.field_attributes', ['default_class' =>  'form-control select2'])
        >
            <option value="">-</option>

            @if (isset($field['model']))
                @foreach ($field['model']::all() as $connected_entity_entry)
                    <option value="{{ $connected_entity_entry->getKey() }}"
                    >{{ $connected_entity_entry->{$field['attribute']} }}</option>
                @endforeach
            @endif
    </select>
```

And this is the way I am trying to modify the select field selected option

```
    function updateunit(object,name){
    var fieldname;
    fieldname = object.id;
    fieldname = fieldname.replace('product_id','order_unit');


    /* data:'_token = <?php echo csrf_token() ?>', */
    $.ajax({
           type:'POST',
           url:'/getmsg',
           data: {id:object.value},
           async: false,
           success:function(data) {
               alert(fieldname);
               alert(data.msg);
              document.getElementById(fieldname).value = data.msg;
           },
           error:function(){alert('Unidade de Compra não está definida')},
    });
```

This is not working, but I have not enough knowledge either on JS neither Angular to understand why this won't bind.

Comment: What exactly happens now? Are the alerts triggered at all?

Comment: Yes, the alerts are triggered, but this select value assignment does not produce any modification, this line does not work `document.getElementById(fieldname).value = data.msg;`

Comment: What is the value of `fieldname` in the alert? Also, can you please add your field configurations for this field and the other field that should be updated?

Comment: Are these select2 elements? if so, could you try `$('#'+fieldname).val(data.msg).trigger('change')` ?

Comment: That works, thank you! Can you explain why it has to be that way?

Comment: Glad to hear  it, I've added an answer below to fully explain the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

The elements that are created by your field configurations use the [jquery select2 plugin](https://select2.org/) to create a fancy select box. It does this by hiding the plain `select` element then displaying an html structure that builds the fancy dropdown etc in its place.

`document.getElementById(fieldname).value = data.msg;` will set the value of the hidden select field, but will not update the value shown by the plugin's fancy html dropdown.

To make the value that's display by the plugin change, we have to call `.trigger('change')` so the select element tells any listening javascript (ie the select2 plugin) that it's internal value has changed and the plugin should now update its display to match. ie, run this:

`$('#'+fieldname).val(data.msg).trigger('change')`

[See more detailed documentation here](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items)